# How to restrict access to particular configmap in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I need to restrict edit access on a particular configmap in kubernets and for remaining cm everybody should get access.

I tried to modify RBAC in the following way but no luck, still it is allowing me to edit with kubectl.

```
  rule {
    api_groups = [""]
    resources  = ["configmaps"]
    verbs      = ["get", "list", "delete", "watch", "create", "patch"]
  }
  rule {
    api_groups = [""]
    resources  = ["configmaps"]
    resource_names = ["test-cm"]
    verbs      = ["get"]
  }
```

Please find roles below

Role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  labels:
     env_name: dev
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    manager: HashiCorp
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-12-03T09:37:59Z"
  name: id0624-role
  namespace: id0624

rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods/log
  - pods
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - patch
  - get
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  - extensions
  resources:
  - deployments
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - patch
  - get
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resourceNames:
  - test-cm
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - patch
  - get
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - patch
  - get
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - patch
  - get
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - patch
  - get
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - batch
  resources:
  - jobs
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - update
  - patch
  - get
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - update
  - patch
  - get
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - update
  - patch
  - get
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - serviceaccounts
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - update
  - patch
  - get
  - delete
```

Find rolebinding below.

We are using AWS IAM roleref.

rolebinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"RoleBinding","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"<name>","namespace":"<name>"},"roleRef":{"apiGroup":"","kind":"Role","name":"<role-name>},"subjects":[{"apiGroup":"","kind":"ServiceAccount","name":"default"}]}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-12-03T09:38:00Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
      f:roleRef:
        f:apiGroup: {}
        f:kind: {}
        f:name: {}
      f:subjects: {}
    manager: HashiCorp
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-12-03T09:38:00Z"
  name: <my-rolebinding
  namespace: <my-namespace>
  resourceVersion: "31585147"
  uid: 431a8b03-f1b8-43e9-ba44-ab85284b56f9
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: <my-app-name>
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
```

Comment: Please provide more details about what you have already tried.
Did you set up any RoleBinding? Did you try to check the authorization through `kubectl auth can-i`?

Comment: yeah, I have configured respective rolebindings. 
User is able to see all other k8s objects including configmaps but Ideally I want to get read-only access on "test-cm" configmap.

Comment: Could you please share the yaml files related to the roles and rolebindings?

Comment: @EmidioNeto , I have updated role and rolebinding info in my main post